# ELMAH filtering not working

Tags: asp.net, filtering, elmah

I have the following settings in my web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
        <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="MyConnHere" />
</elmah>

<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />            
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

And the following in my global.asax file:

```
public void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    Filter(e);
}

public void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    Filter(e);
}

private void Filter(ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    var context = e.Context as HttpContext;

    if (context != null && context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        e.Dismiss();

    if (e.Exception.GetBaseException() is FileNotFoundException ||
        e.Exception.GetBaseException() is HttpRequestValidationException)
        e.Dismiss();
}
```

And yet every single time, Elmah logs 404 exceptions. I'm using ASP.NET MVC; they show up as type System.Web.HttpException, not FileNotFound exception, but the status code is still 404 and so the filter should match, but it doesn't appear to be working at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It turns out that the status code reads 200... why?

Comment: The response status code is 200, but the exception reads: "A public action method 'Register3' could not be found on controller 'controllernamehere'."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer. The Filter method needs to check the result of the  HttpException.GetHttpCode() method, rather than checking the Response.StatusCode property.

```
private void Filter(ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    var exception = e.Exception.GetBaseException();
    var httpException = exception as HttpException;

    if (httpException != null && 
        httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        e.Dismiss();

    if (exception is FileNotFoundException ||
        exception is HttpRequestValidationException ||
        exception is HttpException)
        e.Dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was having the same problem and your post helped.  Out of interest though, and I am probably being dense here but the combination of if statements are baffling me because the second if is checking for all HttpExceptions and dismissing so the first statement would be pointless as the exception would be dismissed anyway?  Thanks  Paul

Comment: Paulie, you're right. I probably shouldn't have included HttpException in the second if statement, since I only wanted to ignore specific HttpExceptions where the status code was 404.